# React App Keep Reloading until it get crashed

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, reload

I am new to react js, I created a react app, and whenever I try to open the app it continuously reloads. can anyone help me in this? i tried but unable to find out any perfect solution.

Any solution?

> package.json

```
{
  "name": "sf",
  "author": "KKK Team",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "/sfrs",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "env-cmd -f .env.development react-scripts start",
    "build:development": "env-cmd -f .env.development react-scripts build",
    "build:nonprod": "env-cmd -f .env.nonprod react-scripts build",
    "build:production": "env-cmd -f .env.production react-scripts build",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "jest --verbose",
    "test:dev": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --silent --watchAll",
    "test:coverage": "jest --silent --coverage",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@date-io/date-fns": "^1.3.13",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.7.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.6.0",
    "@material-table/core": "^0.2.20",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.3.1",
    "@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.66",
    "@mui/material": "^5.3.1",
    "@mui/styles": "^5.3.0",
    "axios": "^0.25.0",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "clsx": "^1.1.1",
    "crypto-browserify": "^3.12.0",
    "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "msal": "^1.4.16",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-perfect-scrollbar": "^1.5.8",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "react-router": "^6.2.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1",
    "recompose": "^0.30.0",
    "redux": "^4.1.2",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.1",
    "stream-browserify": "^3.0.0",
    "sweetalert2": "^11.4.8",
    "sweetalert2-react-content": "^4.2.0",
    "util": "^0.12.4",
    "validator": "^13.7.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "eslint": "^7.11.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.11.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.4",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.20.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.0.8",
    "husky": "^4.2.3",
    "jest-canvas-mock": "^2.3.1",
    "lint-staged": "^10.0.8",
    "prettier": "^1.19.1",
    "react-error-overlay": "^6.0.9",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "setupFiles": [
      "jest-canvas-mock"
    ]
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged",
      "pre-push": "npm run test"
    }
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "src/**/*.{js,jsx,json,css}": [
      "prettier --write",
      "eslint --fix"
    ]
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "@babel/preset-react",
      [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        {
          "targets": {
            "node": "current"
          }
        }
      ]
    ],
    "plugins": [
      [
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
        {
          "loose": true
        }
      ]
    ]
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "react-error-overlay": "6.0.9"
  }
}
```

> I am using MUI 5. I have tried with upgrading and degrading the node version but unable to solve the issue.

> app.jsx

```
import 'react-perfect-scrollbar/dist/css/styles.css';
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useRoutes } from 'react-router-dom';
import _ from 'lodash';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material';
import AuthProvider from './components/auth_provider';
import GlobalStyles from './components/globalstyles';
import theme from './theme/theme';
import AuthenticationProgressLoader from './components/authentication_progress_loader';
import UnAuthorized from './components/unauthorized';
import routeManager from './lib/route.manager';
import Alerts from './components/c_alert';
import PageProgress from './components/c_page_progress';
import PermissionManager from './lib/permission.manager';

const App = props => {
  const {
    userAccount,
    userPermissions,
    graphProfile,
    routesConfig,
    alerts,
    isPageLoader
  } = props;
  const routing = useRoutes(routesConfig || []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (
      !_.isEmpty(userPermissions) &&
      PermissionManager.isUserMerchant() &&
      _.isEmpty(routesConfig)
    ) {
      routeManager.dispatchRoutes();
    }
  }, [routesConfig, userPermissions]);

  return !userPermissions ||
    (!_.isEmpty(userPermissions) && !PermissionManager.isUserMerchant()) ? (
    <UnAuthorized />
  ) : (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <GlobalStyles />
      {!_.isEmpty(alerts.message) && <Alerts />}
      {isPageLoader && <PageProgress />}
      {userAccount && graphProfile && !_.isEmpty(userPermissions) ? (
        routing
      ) : (
        <AuthenticationProgressLoader />
      )}
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};

App.propTypes = {
  // eslint-disable-next-line react/forbid-prop-types
  userAccount: PropTypes.object,
  // eslint-disable-next-line react/forbid-prop-types
  graphProfile: PropTypes.object,
  // eslint-disable-next-line react/forbid-prop-types
  userPermissions: PropTypes.object,
  // eslint-disable-next-line react/forbid-prop-types
  routesConfig: PropTypes.array,
  // eslint-disable-next-line react/forbid-prop-types
  alerts: PropTypes.object,
  isPageLoader: PropTypes.bool
};

App.defaultProps = {
  userAccount: {},
  graphProfile: {},
  userPermissions: {},
  routesConfig: [],
  alerts: {},
  isPageLoader: false
};

function mapStatesToProps(state) {
  const { userPermissions, graphProfile, userAccount } = state.auth;
  const { routesConfig } = state.routes;
  const { alerts } = state;
  const { isPageLoader } = state.pageProgress;
  return {
    userPermissions,
    graphProfile,
    userAccount,
    routesConfig,
    alerts,
    isPageLoader
  };
}

const authApp = AuthProvider(App);
const connectedApp = connect(mapStatesToProps, null)(authApp);
// eslint-disable-next-line
export { connectedApp as App };
```

Comment: You need to post the JSX application code, package.json is not helpful in your case.

Comment: i've added app.jsx

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong there, but one thing you could investigate is whether any `useEffect` changes (directly or indirectly) any of its dependencies.